# Cannot install python library, pycontradictions, within an anaconda environment (jupyter notebooks)

Tags: python, installation, pip, nlp, anaconda

I am working on an NLP project and I am trying to download `pycontradictions` to deal with negations in text. Ex "wasn't" -> "was not". However when I try to install using `conda install pycontractions` I get the following error:

```
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done

Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- pycontractions
```

I have tried fixing with `conda config --append channels conda-forge` but to no avail. Is it possible to download this library into a conda environment? And if not then are there other solutions to deal with contractions? I am planning on just creating a custom dictionary if there are no libraries that can handle contradictions. Thanks!

Comment: Is the library called `pycontractions` or `pycontradictions`? You seem to be using the words interchangeably, when they are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

The `pycontractions` package is not available through Conda. Instead, install it through Pip.

```bash
## activate the environment of interest (should not be 'base')
conda activate my_env

## ensure pip is installed
conda install pip

## install the package
pip install pycontradictions
```

Please read the Conda documentation, ["*Installing Non-Conda Packages.*"](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-non-conda-packages)